# Footer Showing White Bar on only one page of website

Tags: html, css, footer

I am having an issue with this one page where the footer is placing a white bar at the bottom. I would like it to stick to the bottom. I can't really use a sticky footer because it was causing problems with other items on our website.

The other pages I use this footer I am not having this issue (http://www.bkd.com/new-test-2.htm).

Here is the actual page with the footer issue: http://www.bkd.com/industries/private-equity/test-pe-resources.htm

Here is the CSS:

```
#footer3 {padding:36px 0px; background: url(/images/common/footer/footer-black.png)     top repeat-x #000; background-repeat:text-align:left; width: auto; font-size:14px; font-weight:normal;}
#footer3-contents { margin:10px; width: auto; padding-left: 90px;}
#footer3 h2 { color:#fff;  font-size:12px; padding-left:0px; }
#footer3 h2 a { color:#fff; }
#footer3 a { color:#fff; }
#footer3 #footer-legal ul { padding: 0px; margin:0px 0px 0px 0px;}
#footer3 #footer-legal ul li {float:left; padding: 2px 10px 2px 0px;}
```

Any ideas of how to stop this in the future?

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: You have a div on that page `<div id="scroll_tip" class="scroll_colors"></div>` that's causing the space. Script generated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

adding `#scroll_tip {display:none;}` will do the trick, but I am not entirely sure what other effects that may have.